# R text encoding

Tags: r, character-encoding

The [R Data Import/Export Manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html#Encodings) says that there is a good way to guess the encoding of a text file is to use the "file" command line tool (available in R tools). How would one use this? I already have the newest version of Rtools installed. Is this something I can do from my R session? Or do I need to open up the command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of [R Data Import/Export Manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html#Encodings), I interpret it as using a `file` on a command prompt.

However you can invoke a system command with [system()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html) function from R. For example if I have a file called mpi.R in the current directory, I can do:

```
> foo <- system('file mpi.R', intern=TRUE, ignore.stdout=FALSE,   ignore.stderr=TRUE, wait=TRUE)
> print(foo)
[1] "mpi.R: ASCII text"
```

Comment: So, would I pass something like system(paste("file", fileName)) ?

Answer (score 1):

The "command prompt" here refers to a "Terminal" window (OS X or Linux) or "Command Prompt" (Windows).  From these, you have access to the command-line `file` utility, which as the manual states, provides a good description of the type and format of (text) files.

You can also run this straight from R, using the `system()` function to pass the call to `file`.  For example, on my system, in the current working directory I have three text files:

```
> list.files(pattern = "*.txt")
[1] "00005802.txt"                                 "googlebooks-eng-all-totalcounts-20120701.txt"
[3] "sentences.txt"                               
> system("file *.txt")
00005802.txt:                                 Par archive data
googlebooks-eng-all-totalcounts-20120701.txt: ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
sentences.txt:                                ASCII English text, with very long lines
```

It could be that file will call something "plain ASCII" when it only contains the lower 128 ASCII characters, but this will be the same as UTF-8 since those two encodings share the same 8-bit mappings of the first 128 ASCII characters.

Also, file is not always right -- for instance the `00005802.txt` is in fact UTF-8 encoded text that I converted from a pdf using `pdftotext`.

Also beware that on most Windows platforms, you cannot set your system locale to UTF-8 in R.  Try `Sys.getlocale()`.  (To set it, use `Sys.setlocale()`).